# How to pass argument/file name using a for loop to a command line instruction in a Python script?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have following the link:
to incorporate a command line command into my python script and it is working fine. 
but i want o run the command over all the files present in a folder. How to send the file name to the command line? I think there should be some for loop but I cant hit the chord. Also I wnat to save the result in a .csv file.

```
import os
 import subprocess

 list_files = subprocess.run(["file","my_audio.wav"])
```

How to ?

```
for file_name in folder
      output=subprocess.run(["file","file_name"])`
      save output in .csv
```

Comment: General programming questions are off topic.

Comment: Ask this in programming section please.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the glob module for the file names:

```
import glob
print(glob.glob("/home/pi/*.py"))
```

This will print a list of python files in the Pi home directory.  Save this to a variable and loop over this.

As for csv output (my least favourite file format) then  look at the [Python csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

The reason why I hate csv - I once spent days on an AS/400 trying to work out why file transfers failed and discovered lots of 12" Pizza products despite being told it was a clean file...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pipe feature in the command line and include the argparse library for python command line input. The bash execution would go something like `$ ls | python myFile.py` where you could customize the `ls` arguments. Your python file could then take the arguments passed to it using `args = parser.parse_args()`. I would look into the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) library more as well.